# Condition for multiplication table to be associative, from Rotman.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm reading Rotman's Group Theory for fun. I got stuck on exercise 1.42(iv). It goes as:

Let $G=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be a set with binary operation $*$, let $A=[a_{ij}]$ be the multiplication table $a_{ij}=x_i*x_j$. Assume $G$ has two sided inverse $e$. Assume $x_1=e$, so $a_{1i}=x_i$ and $a_{i1}=x_i^{-1}$ for all $i$, and $a_{ii}=e$. Prove $*$ is associative iff $a_{ij}a_{jk}=a_{ik}$ for all $i,j,k$.

Proof: If $*$ is associative,
$$
a_{ij}a_{jk}=x_i*x_j*x_j*x_k=x_i*(x_j*x_j)*x_k=x_i*e*x_k=x_i*x_k=a_{ik}.
$$

The other way is giving me problems. $(x_i*x_j)*x_k=x_i*(x_j*x_k)$ iff $a_{ij}*x_k=x_i*a_{jk}$, so I wrote $x_i=a_{1i}$ and $x_k=a_{1k}$ but I'm not able to do much manipulation since I don't know $*$ is associative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $a_{ij}a_{jk}=a_{ik}$ translates to $(x_i*x_j)*(x_j*x_k)=x_i*x_k$.

Firstly, this implies $x_j*(x_j*x_k)=(x_1*x_j)*(x_j*x_k)=x_1*x_k=x_k$ for all $j,k$.

Then $(x_i*x_j)*x_k=(x_i*x_j)*(x_j*(x_j*x_k))=x_i*(x_j*x_k)$.